# How to execute a .sh file?

Tags: executable, .sh

I just install Ubuntu. One of the things I miss about windows is the lack of executable.

When I right click the .sh file, go to permissions, and check "Allow executing as a program", it never does execute as a program when I double click it.

Another solution I found is doing it in the terminal. This doesn't work either. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this really too stupid of a question or am I too stupid? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just try this, no need to make it executable: `sh ./ts3client_runscript.sh` and see what happens, you're probably running it correctly, but the application doesn't work (crash, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

After you run chmod +x your shell script became executable. Now you can run it

```
./ts3client_runscript.sh
```

from the directory script lives in. Its a bit tricky, don't forget to put ./ in front of shell script file name.

Comment: The "./" is only needed when the script is not in your execution path.  On Ubuntu, the current directory is not searched for executables by default, only the execution path.  Specifying "./" forces it to search the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

After giving it the permission to run then go to edit menu and click on preferences, then click on behavior tab, after that you will see an entry named "Executable text files" there check the 'Ask each time' radio button.
Now you can run it by double clicking and by selecting 'run'.

Answer (score 1):

For executing script in Linux first of all you have to give full permission.

**commands for full permission:**

```
 sudo chmod 777 ts3client_runscript.sh

       or

 sudo chmod a+x ts3client_runscript.sh
```

**then you can run your script by this command**

```
 ./ts3client_runscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done by running the command `chmod +x nameofshell.sh` is, you made the shell to be executable as a program. Now it is executable, so that you can execute it. You cant make the execution process by simply double clicking it. To do this,Open terminal by alt+ctrl+T, go to the directory containing the shell using the command `cd /path/to/location/` and then type

```
./nameofshell.sh
```

Hit enter! Done!

Comment: `/path/to/location/nameofshell.sh` should be sufficient--after all, `./` works because it causes the name to contain a `/` character and thus be interpreted as the path to a specific script to be run (preventing `$PATH` from being searched instead). The only situation where `cd /path/to location; ./nameofshell.sh` would be necessary is if the script is written in such a way as to assume it's run with the present working directory as its own location, or if the user otherwise needs to be in that directory for something they are doing.

Comment: Ya, you said the point right. But I just wrote the most widely used method here because he seems to be a newcomer to shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

open the file to check if the sha bang (first line) is #!/bin/bash.
after this, try to execute the file by using shell like this:
 `sh your_file.sh`

Comment: The "sh" is not strictly necessary, you just need to make sure the executable bit is set, then you can run it as in `/path/to/script.sh`

Comment: but he have to know if the right shell is selected

Comment: The shebang should take care of that - as you describe in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @BriceFouthe A `#!/bin/bash` hashbang line causes it to be run by `bash` when invoked as `./your_file.sh` (or `/path/to/your_file.sh`). But `sh your_file.sh` runs it with `sh` (which on Ubuntu is a different shell from `bash`; `sh` is `dash`). I recommend editing this answer to clarify what shell you're recommending attempting to run the script with (or what the considerations are that you'd suggest be taken into account when deciding that). Without that information, it's not really clear how best to use this answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about this command:

```
sudo sh ts3client_runscript.sh
```

Comment: "sudo" is not necessary unless for some reason the script needs to be run with superuser privileges.  "sh" is not necessary unless the script has no executable permission set.

Comment: Running the script by passing it as an argument to `sh` may be necessary if the script has no hashbang line and the shell being used isn't `sh`, or if the script's hashbang line is something other than `#!/bin/sh` but the user wants to force it to be run with `sh` instead. (And usually, `sh scriptname` must be replaced with `./scriptname` or some other path to the script containing a `/`.)